# Programming practice: How to separate concerns regarding sql access (in python)?

Tags: python, mysql, paradigms

In python I want to handle all SQL accesses through a separate library `sql.py`; only this library creates the SQl queries and makes the queries the database. Is this meaningful?

I have another python-module `data.py` that represents some data and contains some logic, and that does not know about how the data is stored in the database. On the other hand, `sql.py` does not know of any structure of `data.py`.

Now to efficiently update some data in the database I need to construct a list of multiple queries that are passed on to the database before committing. But where to do that? I can either make this list of queries in `data.py`, but then `data.py` knows something about the structure of the database. Or I do this in `sql.py`, but then `sql.py` needs to know something about the structure of `data.py`. How to do this 'right'?

Comment: Write a library glue.py which takes higher level data from data.py and converts it into relevant instructions for sql.py. glue.py will have to know about the database structure

Comment: and glue.py needs to know about the structure of data.py?

Comment: yes, it needs to. Using that information it will create required sql queries

Comment: But this sounds even like a worse idea! Instead of updating code in only one module now I am required to update code in two modules all the time, no matter if the database structure changes or if the structure in `data.py` changes. That is actually the point I want to avoid...

Comment: I suppose you check out SQLAlchemy and/or the Peewee python packages. They do pretty much what your `sql.py` is supposed to do.

Comment: Its a simple project, I do not want to checkout any additional modules.

Comment: But I will take a look at peewee, thanks